# qt performance – OpenGL

Tags: qt, qt4, embedded-linux

i wan't to use Native OpenGL in the paint function of my widgets(QPainter), to improve performance.
i saw that there is function QPainter::begin/endNativePainting(), that can help me.
but i can't find examples for that...
i wanted to know if those functions are low cost, or evry use of them reduce performance?
2.can i define beginNativePainting() and endNativePainting(), in general for all the widgets i use, instead of using that in every paint function i have.

tnx for any help....

Answer (score 1):

There is some basic example code right in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting

The functions themselves should be fairly low-cost, but calling them might still cause a noticeably overhead, because Qt has to flush its internal painting queue on the `beginNativePainting()` call and probably has to assume that everything is changed as soon as `endNativePainting()` is called.

For the second part I am not sure if I understand what you are aiming at. Basically if you have a QPainter object, you can call `beginNativePainting()` once. But you have to match it with an `endNativePainting()` call. So the usual place would be the paint() method.

Comment: i saw this example, but there is no program (in qt examples/demos/nokia-forum) that use it... and i wonder if it's realy usefull, or there is other way to do so.                                                           2. if i'm going to use it for lot of widgets in the application, i can put the beginNativePainting() in the ctor of QWidget... and the endNativePainting() in th dtor? ..... is it realy useful when i have a lot of widget?

Comment: The Qt framework provides you with a QPainter as a parameter to the paintEvent() method of your QWidget. Using begin/endNativePainting() makes only sense inside this method (as long as the QPainter exists). So you cannot simply call beginNativePainting() in the ctor (on what?) If you are not sure what you are doing, I'd advise to just use the QPainter to paint and ignore begin/endNativePainting(). Only if you run into some issue you cannot solve with Qt's API, that might be the time to reconsider. (If all you are after is to use OpenGL, you might want to have a look at Qt's graphics systems.)

Comment: i have to use the opengl to improve the perfomance.... i wan't to know what is the best way to do that without changing a lot of parts in my widgets code.

Comment: So you aren't using OpenGL at all at the moment? Then begin/endNativePainting() to use native OpenGL calls wouldn't work anyway.Try running your application with "-graphicssystem opengl" as (additional) command line parameter. That switches Qt's default render backend to OpenGL, no change in your code required. If that works and is noticeably (or at least measurably) faster, you can change your application initialization to set the default backend with something like QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("opengl"), see http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#setGraphicsSystem

Comment: i use this but i got error: QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
Failed to create pixmap texture buffer of size  QSize(158, 17) , falling back to raster paint engine

Comment: Hmm. That sounds like there is something wrong with the Qt OpenGL support on your platform. You'll have to get that working first, before any of the stuff discussed here makes any sense. I'd say, try to get this resolved in another question if needed, providing more info about the environment. If you are not dead-set on OpenGL you can also try "-graphicssystem raster". On many devices this yields better performance than the native backend.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is using a range of OpenGL functionalities to implement its 2D painting, including custom shaders and various frame buffers. It puts OpenGL into a pretty messy state.

`beginNativePainting` / `endNativePainting` are there to allow Qt's drawing engine to save this context and retrieve it once the user is done drawing.

It would have been nice to have the `xxxNativePainting` methods do the contrary (i.e. automatically save and restore user configuration of OpenGL), but since Qt allows to call OpenGL primitives directly, saving the global state is nigh impossible without tons of code and potential serious performance hit.

Instead, these methods simply save Qt's internal OpenGL state and, rather than having user code start in a configuration that would be meaningless anyway (and likely to change with each new Qt release), reset OpenGL to a "neutral" state.
It means that, inside a begin/end section, you will start with a clean slate: no shader linked, no vertex array, most of global parameters reset, etc.

Contrary to a simple `QGLWidget` / `PaintGL` scenario where you can afford to setup the global OpenGL state once and for all and simply call the rendering primitives each frame, you will have to restore pretty much everything just after the call to `beginNativePainting` (link/bind your shaders, set global parameters, select and enable various buffers, etc).

It also means that you should use native painting sparringly. Having each single widget do custom painting might soon bring your rendering to its knees.